# ES6: How to reuse a const variable in multiple files of the library BUT WITHOUT exposing it to client code?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

I am writing a library which is made up of several files:

```
./lib:
 - core.js
 - file1.js
 - file2.js
 - file3.js
```

`lib/core.js` contains common variables which I need to reuse in `file1.js`, `file2.js` and `file3.js`.

E.g., `core.js`:

```
/**
 * I would like to reuse this constant in file1.js, file2.js and file3.js,
 * but I don't want client code to be able to access the value of this constant
 * when importing components of my library, like "aFunction" below.
 */
export const CONSTANT_I_WANT_TO_REUSE_IN_OTHER_FILES_OF_THE_LIBRARY = 'Some value';

/**
 * I would like to expose this function to client code
 * as well as to the other files of the library (file1.js, file2.js and file3.js).
 */
export const aFunction = () => {
}

...
```

Then `file1.js` (`file2.js` and `file3.js` are similar):

```
import { CONSTANT_I_WANT_TO_REUSE_IN_OTHER_FILES_OF_THE_LIBRARY } from './core'

/**
 * This function should be available to the client code (as "aFunction" of core.js),
 * but CONSTANT_I_WANT_TO_REUSE_IN_OTHER_FILES_OF_THE_LIBRARY should not.
 */
export const file1Function = () => {
    // Need to use `CONSTANT_I_WANT_TO_REUSE_IN_OTHER_FILES_OF_THE_LIBRARY` here
    console.log(CONSTANT_I_WANT_TO_REUSE_IN_OTHER_FILES_OF_THE_LIBRARY)
}
```

How can I achieve this using ES6 modules? Right now, with this setup, `CONSTANT_I_WANT_TO_REUSE_IN_OTHER_FILES_OF_THE_LIBRARY` is also available to client code.

But I would like to keep it "module-private", i.e. only available to my library code.

Thank you for the attention.

Comment: Do not export that constant. Just declare it, assign a value and use in some function. Then export that function. You can add `getter` also.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Could you provide an example, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IF you don't want any variable to be visible outside your module (file) then just declare it and assign a value inside your module but do not export that variable.In your `core.js`:

```
const CONSTANT_I_WANT_TO_REUSE_IN_OTHER_FILES_OF_THE_LIBRARY = 'Some value';

export const getThatVariable = () => CONSTANT_I_WANT_TO_REUSE_IN_OTHER_FILES_OF_THE_LIBRARY;

export const aFunction = () => {
}
```

In your `file1.js`:

```
import { getThatVariable } from "./core.js"


export const file1Function = () => {
    const neededVariable = getThatVariable();
    console.log(neededVariable);
}
```

Comment: There's no other way, right? client code can still access `getThatVariable`.

Comment: He doesn't acces your variable, he just can get it's value. But he won't be able to change that. Unless you give him that opportunity using `setter`. But that is different story)

Comment: I just shown you the simpliest way, but you can "mask" getting that variable in some other way too.

Comment: `But he won't be able to change that. ` Even without using the getter, client code won't be able to change `CONSTANT_I_WANT_TO_REUSE_IN_OTHER_FILES_OF_THE_LIBRARY ` as it is defined with `const`